# bootcamp thunderbolt ethernet windows 10 slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, ethernet, boot-camp

Lately I've been having trouble with my macBook Pro bought 2016. I have windows 10 in bootcamp and have connected ethernet cable through ethernet-thunderbolt adapter. When I start windows my internet speed is below 1 Mb/s and it should normally be 8 Mb/s. There is no problem with ISP or router because I have another PC connected to the same router and there the speed is normal.
Than I do some woodoo like unplug the adapter from one thunderbolt and plug it in another, unplug ethernet cable from the adapter and plug it back in etc. and after some attempts speed gets back to normal.
What is wrong?

Also it started overheating lately when I'm doing nothing especially like browsing the internet. Don't know exact temperature but it's hot on touch and fan is working like crazy which before only happened when I was playing demanding games. Don't know if its related.

It might be that this started to happen when I installed new bootcamp drivers or AMD drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was fault of AMD drivers. I uninstalled everything except display drivers, and overheating was gone, and with that ethernet connection was working great again, I guess ethernet connection doesn't work good with hot macBook.

Also, my ethernet speed was set to 100Mb/s or "auto". I needed to set it to 10Mb/s, as my speed is a bit below that, than it worked.